# Setting a bg-gradient next.js/tailwind

Tags: css, next.js

In the globle.css I have the following,

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  body{
    @apply bg-sky-900 text-sky-100;
  }
}
```

it renders the color as would expect it to,
but if I use this `@apply bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-400 via-gray-600 to-blue-800`. Is it possible to set a gradient in this way? thanks for any pointer still really new to both next.js & tailwind

Comment: you can see the gradient output and test your configuration via this website that i just found https://hypercolor.dev/generator and yeah your configuration looks working

Comment: i was not able to get it working the way i expected  it to but was able to find a work around in setting the bg out side of the global.css ....thank you for you input though!!